# Kubernetes runAsUser create home directory

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I've been tasked with getting our k8s deployment running as non-Root.
A 3rd party library we use needs the home directory for the user to exist and have write access.
I've tried using initContainers but any changes I make are essentially discarded, and of course I don't have permissions on the real container

I would like to avoid setting all this up in the Dockerfile. Is there anyway to create the user home directory for the user kubernetes container runs as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes uses a container engine to run a pod with a specific image. *Most* Pods can die at any time, therefore they must be either based on an image with the desired state or have state preserved in a different way.

If there is a state that you would like to preserve and using a Dockerfile / Custom Image is not an option, I suggest you either :

1. Set up a volume. 
   volume mount the user directory so that the files are never deleted and permissions are preserved as well.
   https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath
2. Run the container together with a sidecar.
   Create a pod that has a sidecar container which can run commands in the same network and can share a volume mount with the main container.

ie. perhaps you can create a shared volume, then create an image that chowns the directory as root and use this image for a sidecar container.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/#creating-a-pod-that-runs-two-containers

However, the simplest solution could be to just modify permissions in the Dockerfile, for example by adding some lines to a Dockerfile. If you are adding lines to you your existing Dockerfile, make sure to add them before your CMD / ENTRYPOINT

If you are basing this image off of your already existing one, make sure to put this at the top of your Dockerfile

`FROM Myoriginalimage`

Dockerfile commands:

`USER root
RUN chown $USER:$USER_GROUP -R $USER_HOME_DIR
USER $USER`

make sure your CMD/ENTRYPOINT comes after this if you are editing an existing Dockerfile

More info on Dockerfile: https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/containers/how-to-use-dockerfiles/

After that you can push to a registry, such as dockerhub, assuming you don't have a private registry or can't have access to one for whatever reason.

- create an account at hub.docker.com
- tag your image appropriately
- `docker login`
- `docker push your-image`

See here for more details: 
https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/

Comment: Since I _can_ use uid 1000 (i.e. a known uid) on AKS this satisfies my personal requirement, but some setups use random uid and I don't think this can be used for that since you would need to know the uid when you chown. _Maybe_ volumes would work in that case?

Comment: With a theoretical image that is *that* dynamic where the entrypoint script is literally creating and choosing a random user to run as in real time, then sure probably a try something like the sidecar /volume method. But this seems like an unlikely scenario. I recommend you just docker run like usual and run the command id inside the container while its running to test it out.

ie. `docker run --rm --name some-name some-image`

then `docker exec -it some-name id`

the `--rm` deletes the container automatically when you stop it

Comment: This is Kubernetes with the requirement of non-root user. Docker run commands don't come into the equation

Comment: Also that dockerhub stuff is not relevant to the question. I'm using ACR anyway

Comment: kubernetes uses a container engine like docker to run a container based off an image. if you want to know the user in use for a container made from a given image you can kubectl exec into thd pod and run ps to see who runs processes and id to see default user id. same can be simulated with docker run. but better with kubectl exec

Comment: Yeah, I know all that. This has to do with the fact that the home directory is `/` by default which causes all kinds of problems for software that assumes a normal home directory exists. Basically, the user doesn't have a home directory that it can write to unless specifically created in the Dockerfile. Everything outside the scope of a users home directory is not really on topic here.